# RecycleView getting NullPointerException for Android support v7 recycleview

Tags: android-recyclerview

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:834)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:1169)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.addViewHolderToRecycledViewPool(RecyclerView.java:3900)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleCachedViewAt(RecyclerView.java:3843)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:3880)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:3804)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleViewAt(RecyclerView.java:5529)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:1139)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleViewsFromStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:1180)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleByLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:1244)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1268)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1102)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:959)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:3062)
>     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I have This Issue Too , ON AVD Working But on Gnemotion Android 4.2.2 Got This Error !